# Enable GZIP in CakePHP2+

Tags: cakephp

I tryed everything to gzip my files in cakephp, but no sucess. Can someone please help me how to compress all files in cakephp (ctp, js, css, html etc etc etc).. I wanna one faster website!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? can you provide some code that you have already tried ? It will help people answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is pretty obvious, check these two questions.

- [How to check if gzip compression is enabled with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397295/how-to-check-if-gzip-compression-is-enabled-with-php)
- http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-enable-gzip-compress-on-php-websites/